# What is causing "Template parse error near `.', in stanza #2 of /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/templates" error message?

Tags: linux, installation, debian

I have a Debian installation which works on 32-bit Ubuntu, but fails on 64-bit Ubuntu with the message:

**Template parse error near `.', in stanza #2 of /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/templates**

What could be causing that?

Answer (score 1):

After many frustrating hours, I found the answer. I'm posting this so that others can find it on search engines.

In the *templates* file, the *Description* section can be multi-line.

Between paragraphs, you can cause a blank line to appear with a line that has only a period.

However, this period needs to be proceeded by a space.

**Blank lines are: [space][period]**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to delete all lines containing "**@**" (sr@latin.UTF-8)  in /var/lib/dpkg/info/console-data.templates.. Weird but it worked.